# What exactly do the flags do in the re library for python 3?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am unable to find explanations to what exactly the flags due for certain operations within the re library.

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html

for example, I have the following bit of python code:

```
nestedPar = re.findall(r"\([^\(\)]*\)", s, 0)
```

but I am unsure what exactly is happening when I change that 0 to a 1, since it results in a crash.

Can anyone explain what this flag means exactly?

Comment: The docs says nothing about the flag being a 1. But there are multiple examples, e.g. **flags=re.IGNORECASE**

Comment: The flags are documented starting [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.A). Their numeric values are not documented, and you should not pass int constants for the flags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third argument is options bit mask, and bit masks are defined as (this, technically, may vary from version to version):

```
SRE_FLAG_TEMPLATE = 1 # template mode (disable backtracking)
SRE_FLAG_IGNORECASE = 2 # case insensitive
SRE_FLAG_LOCALE = 4 # honour system locale
SRE_FLAG_MULTILINE = 8 # treat target as multiline string
SRE_FLAG_DOTALL = 16 # treat target as a single string
SRE_FLAG_UNICODE = 32 # use unicode locale
SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE = 64 # ignore whitespace and comments
SRE_FLAG_DEBUG = 128 # debugging
```

Using a simple bitwise OR (or your regular `+`) you can combine multiple flags (e.g. `re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL`). It shouldn't fail on `1` but please don't use numbers directly, they are assigned to meaningful constants for a reason.

**EDIT** - Template mode (`re.T` or `re.TEMPLATE`), whose flag is `1` as shown above, is experimental and a lot of things can go wrong with it, directly from the source:

```
# sre extensions (experimental, don't rely on these)
T = TEMPLATE = sre_compile.SRE_FLAG_TEMPLATE # disable backtracking
```

So you've encountered a problem with the templating mode. Either way for happy life, do not set the flags yourself :)

Comment: Sure thing, the string it is crashing on is - a(bc)de

Comment: Just a small nitpick, but _"codified"_ isn't particularly informative into what is meant. Perhaps _"they are assigned to **meaningful constants** for a reason"_ would be better wording?